# INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS - Getting Duplicate Key Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, not-exists

I keep getting a duplicate key error when I execute the below.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to generate this error.  Can someone take a look and see what I'm missing? Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO tblApp_Risk (AppID, BusiRisk, TechRisk, InterimRiskMitigate, RiskMitigateDesc, KeyDriverDesc, ITSvcsKeyDriver,
RMStartOrderReason, ESMVendorRisk, KeyManRisk, MultVersBehind, ProdStabRisk, RegCompRisk, TierArchGap)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        P.AppID1, R.BusiRisk, R.TechRisk, R.InterimRiskMitigate, 
        R.RiskMitigateDesc, R.KeyDriverDesc, R.ITSvcsKeyDriver,
        R.RMStartOrderReason, R.ESMVendorRisk, R.KeyManRisk, R.MultVersBehind, 
        R.ProdStabRisk, R.RegCompRisk, R.TierArchGap
    FROM 
        tblProject P 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblRisk R ON P.ProjID = R.ProjID  
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM tblApp_Risk K 
                    WHERE K.AppID = P.AppID1) 
        AND P.AppID1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: so, if you drop the insert into clause and just run the select, is the result set small enough that you can just visually scan for duplicate keys?  Maybe sort on that field?  Otherwise you can group on that field alone and do counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppID column is most likely creating the error, because I am guessing you have a 1 to many relationship on the join.  You either need to drop the unique constraint on that column or any other key column in the 1 to many relationship, or just not insert that value.  Usually when doing a join insert you would create a key for the dump table that is not the key for the joined tables.  For instance a key column such as AppRiskId.

Comment: The AppID column is a one to many relationship (multiple projects have the same AppID).  I'll try your approach of creating a different key for the table I'm inserting into.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your select `DISTINCT` only filter when all the fields are the same

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        P.AppID1, R.BusiRisk, ...
```

So if you have

```
 field1 field2 field3
 A        B      C
 A        D      E
 X        Y      Z
 X        Y      Z


select distinct field1, field2, field3
```

will return three rows, will filter `X` rows but give you duplicate key for `A`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without seeing your data, but I'd guess that the inner join is a 1 to many so you're trying to insert the same key more than once.